# what does 다다다다 mean??? I found it in a short story

Tags: vocabulary

거의 반말조로 [[ 다다다다]] 내뱉은 경비는 인터폰을 끊어버렸다.

is it onomatopoeia or is the author referring the verb da.

뚜뚜뚜. 경비는 이미 그런 전화를 수십 번 받았는지, 내가 뜨거운,이라고 말하자마자, 아, 밑에 공고도 안 보고 다녀요? 오늘부터 배관 교체 공사한다고 써붙여져 있잖아요. 내가 방송도 여러 수십 번을 했는데 말야. 거의 반말조로 다다다다 내뱉은 경비는 인터폰을 끊어버렸다.
아, 그래서 지금도 나는 궁금하다. 엘리베이터에 낀 그 남자는 어떻게 됐을까. ●

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 다다다다 : onomatopoeic word representing sound of totally automatic
>   gun (=기관단총=submachine gun; It is also called 따발총)

생각나는 대로 다다다다 따발총처럼 (=다다다다) 내뱉다.

I spit words like a submachine gun, following to a flow of my
thought.

다다다다 따발총 쏘듯이 한 말에 태욱은 아 무 대답 없었다.

Taewook did not respond to my word like shooting a submachine gun.

Answer (score 2):

It's mimicking the sound of fast, almost unintelligible speech - so

> 거의 반말조로 [[ 다다다다]]

means something like

> speaking very fast, 'dadadadadada', almost in *ban-mal*